# Spurious wakeup with Semaphore

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I have a doubt: let's assume I have an object of class Semaphore called `sem` and that a thread tries to acquire a permission doing `sem.acquire()` and that there are not, so the thread is suspended. Now if the thread is awakened by a spurious wakeup, what happend? Should I insert the `sem.acquire()` in a sort of loop?

Comment: You should not have to. The so-called 'spurious wakeup' is a basic failure of an OS API call.  It's like a file system that occasionally opens the wrong file by mistake and excuses such disasters by documenting it.  I guess that you would have to look at the docs for the underlying OS.   Windows kernel semaphores, for example, do not suffer from spurious wakeups, ever.

Comment: The Semaphore takes care of that for you. Otherwise, it would be documented, as it is for `Object.wait()`.

Answer (score 1):

Only the very basic `Object.wait()` method is subjected to spurious wakeups (actually only the Unsafe.park() method, but there is no way to access that without hacks), all more sophisticated tools deal with that internally.

If you have a look at the actual code of `Semaphore.acquireUninterruptibly()` you'll find the following construct (hidden in `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireShared()`):

```
for (;;) {
    // ... try aquire, else:
    if (shouldParkAfterFailedAcquire(p, node) &&
        parkAndCheckInterrupt())
        interrupted = true;
}
```

The `for(;;)` loop is basically a `while(true)` loop, so even though `parkAndCheckInterrupt()` can spuriously wake up, the loop will ensure that this will just cause another failed tryAquire run, then it will be put back to sleep.

Comment: You may or may not consider `Condition` "more sophisticated" but it is also subject to spurious wakeups

Comment: I thought spurious wakeup was a thing of the past... I may be confusing that with double-check locking (not longer being required). Do you have some up to date references / links talking about spurious wakeup? Most of what I google is years old. thx